# TabIndex property, multiple tabindexes inside eachother?

Tags: html, css, double, focus, tabindex

Is it possible to have multiple elements (set with the **tabIndex** property) inside eachother, while still having focus on the 'main' parent?

In case my question doesn't make sense at all, here's an example:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5ppgnyk/1/)

```
<div class="parent" tabindex="-1">
    <div tabindex="-1">
        <h2>Header 1</h2>
        <div>
            <h2>Header 1.1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <div>
            <h2>Header 2.1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically the **'desired outcome'** is what I want to achieve while having focus on it's main parent (the element with the class 'parent'). Currently, when having focus on the children (which also have the tabIndex attribute set) the main parent loses its focus (which is obvious). But how can I work-around this issue?

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/e5ppgnyk/2/ ?

Comment: @TylerH Well.. at long end, yes. But it also has to be 'collapsable''

Comment: So when you click on "click here", it opens "Header 1 and Header 2", and when you click on "Header 1", it opens "Header 1.1", etc.?

Comment: @TylerH Yes, exactly! (and that in pure CSS, using tabIndexes)